# Ruby on rails file download using form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page where I upload a list of users to an action upload data. There on success/failure it lists me the list of invalid users. This is a one time action the lsit of users is not saved to database. I need to be able to write these user list to a file and allow the user to download this file. I do not have a clue on how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what type of file do you want that your user download?

Comment: just a plain text file that will contain the list of invalid users in csv format.

Answer (score 3):

```
1. require the CSV library to controller

require 'csv'

2. Code in controller

    def export_to_csv
       #get all invalid users here and then modify according to yoou logic       
        @users = User.find(:all)
        csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
             csv << ["Id", "Name", "status","Role"]
             @users.each do |user|
               csv << [user.id, user.name, user.status, user.role]
             end
        end         

       send_data csv_string,
       :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
       :disposition => "attachment; filename=users.csv" 
    end
```

Comment: or you also can use send_file

Comment: the problem is I do not have the list of users of in database. I upload a file that contains list of certain users those are to be validated against set of buildings. This list is generated when my upload data action completes this is one time action.

Comment: when you upload a file and if some users are invalid you can put those users in an array and then generate csv file..